Unable to network KVM on bridged interface with bonded interface slave
I am unable to access a KVM over the network when its network is a bridge with a bonded interface as a slave. Here's how I create bonded interface bond0:
sudo nmcli connection add type bond con-name bond0 ifname bond0 bond.options "mode=802.3ad"
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet slave-type bond con-name bond0-port1 ifname eno1np0 master bond0
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet slave-type bond con-name bond0-port2 ifname eno2np1 master bond0

Here's what /proc/net/bonding/bond0 shows:
Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP active: on
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 15
    Partner Key: 3
    Partner Mac Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:03

Slave Interface: eno1np0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01
    port key: 15
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 127
    system mac address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:03
    oper key: 3
    port priority: 127
    port number: 1
    port state: 63

Slave Interface: eno2np1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:02
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01
    port key: 15
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 127
    system mac address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:03
    oper key: 3
    port priority: 127
    port number: 17
    port state: 63

Here's how the ports are configured on the LAG on the switch:
> show lacp interfaces ae2
Aggregated interface: ae2
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/0/2 FUP    Actor   No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/2 FUP  Partner   No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Slow    Active
      xe-1/0/2       Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/2     Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Slow    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-0/0/2                  Current   Slow periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/2                  Current   Slow periodic Collecting distributing

Here's how I create bridge kvbr0:
sudo nmcli con add ifname kvbr0 type bridge con-name kvbr0
sudo nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname bond0 master kvbr0

sudo nmcli con mod kvbr0 ipv4.addresses 10.192.161.200/24
sudo nmcli con mod kvbr0 ipv4.gateway 10.192.161.1
sudo nmcli con mod kvbr0 ipv4.dns "10.250.0.26 10.122.64.26 10.194.0.26"
sudo nmcli con mod kvbr0 ipv4.method manual

Here's how I create the VM:
sudo virt-install
--virt-type kvm  --name kvm1 --ram 4096  --vcpus 2  --disk size=20
--os-variant rocky9  --network network=bridged-network  --graphics none
--location /tmp/Rocky-9.4-x86_64-minimal.iso  --check all=off
--initrd-inject /tmp/kvm1.cfg --extra-args="inst.ks=file:/kvm1.cfg console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"
--noautoconsole  --autostart  --wait -1

bridged-network consists of bridge kvbr0.
Here are the settings for the interface on the VM:
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:5a:01:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.192.161.201/24 brd 10.192.161.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe5a:1ed/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I can ping bond0 and kvbr0, but I do not get a ping response for the interface on the KVM. On the host, I see an ARP request for the VM's IP on both eno2np1 and bond0. tcpdump shows that bond0 has traffic for both the interfaces. None of this traffic is forwarded to eno1np0 on the VM or the tap interface vnet11.
If I do tcpdump on enp1s0 in the VM, I see STP frames from the bridge.
If I create another VM, each VM can ping each other. I can also run a python web server and curl the IP of another VM (after disabling firewalld).
Here's what I see for bridge link:
4: eno1np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1316 master bond0 hwmode VEB
5: eno2np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1316 master bond0 hwmode VEB
6051: vnet11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1316 master kvbr0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100

The host is running Rocky9.3 and the VM is running Rocky9.4. Both are running kernel 5.14.

Is "mode=active-backup" actually correct for LACP? (AFAIK that's a static LAG, non-LACP, mode...) Does your switch show the LACP LAG details?

Yes, the LAG is configured as active/passive on the switch. mode=active-backup seemed like the most appropriate choice on the Linux side.

I am not 100% sure if I have everything here right, but I'm about 80% sure:

bond.options "mode=active-backup"

That's a static LAG mode, and likely incompatible with the switch expecting LACP.
You need to use mode=802.3ad for LACP bonds.

Yes, the LAG is configured as active/passive on the switch

No it is not. LACP LAGs are always "active/active" (with automatic failover).
In the context of LACP, the Activity setting defines peer role, not port role – an 'active' peer will initiate the LACP negotiation, a 'passive' peer will not. So if a port were set to 'passive' on both sides, the LAG would never come up on that port at all (because both would wait for someone else to start the LACP handshake) and it would just remain a stand-alone port.
(In other words, if I am reading the switch output correctly, you probably have xe-0/0/2 non-operational as it's set to 'active' and forever trying to negotiate LACP – which the server doesn't respond because its bond is not in the LACP mode – while xe-1/0/2 due to being 'passive' is operating as a standalone port and just waiting for the server to speak LACP first.)
All ports of the LAG should be set to the same mode.

Setting mode=802.3ad didn't help. I'll check the switch settings. Considering I'm able to ping the bridge but not the VM on the bridge imply that mean the switch settings are not causing the problem I'm seeing? The VM is getting the ARP requests, but there is no reply.

My guess is that it is replying through a different port... Has the switch's output changed in any way after setting the bond mode on Linux? Can you check the contents of /proc/net/bonding/bond0 on the server and add it to your post?

Thanks, I updated the question. The VM only has enp1s0 and lo. Should I see a reply on enp1s0?

I meant that the frame gets lost because the server's bond0 sends it through a different port because of the mode mismatch with the switch. With 802.3ad(LACP) now active, though, that should no longer be the case.

Also... I looked closer at the ARP request you quoted in the post – that's not an ARP request that the VM gets; it's an ARP request the VM sends. Can you see any traffic in tcpdump (preferably with -e) that actually comes to the VM from outside?

Yes, I se STP frames from the bridged interface on the host.

Those come from the bridge itself, so they don't really count – does tcpdump show anything else, primarily through the switch? And just to be sure, are all the bridge ports in STP 'forwarding' state?

tcpdump shows nothing else. The bridge has bridge.stp yes. There is no bridge setting on bond0 interface.

I know it has bridge.stp yes, because of the STP frames; thus the question about the per-port STP state, as shown by brctl showstp or bridge link. (Do you want to use the 'classic' STP on your network, though? It famously takes a whole minute to converge – generally not something you want on a modern network.) What about tcpdump on the corresponding interfaces on the host? If something else in the network broadcasts ARP requests, do they arrive at bond0 on the host? And if they do – does the host forward them to the tap0 interface corresponding to the VM?

I don't see per-port STP state. tcpdump shows ARP requests on both bond0 and one of the interfaces. Nothing is forwarded to the interface on the VM or the tap interface vnet11.

This seems to be a bug. Even though I had added bond0 to the bridge, brctl did not show it as a member:
sudo brctl show kvbr0
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
kvbr0       8000.fe540093cf9f   no      vnet1

I added bond0 using sudo brctl addif kvbr0 bond0, and now I'm able to access the VM from the network
